# SP2010 Foundation Modal Pop Up not working for a list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, modal-dialog

I just upgraded wss 3.0 site to sp2010 foundation. Upgrade went fine without any problems. When i was testing the new system i can into a problem with a custom list. When i click add new item in a list it doesnt give me that nice modal pop up dialog box like other lists do in my site. It navigates me to the full page.
 I checked the list setting-->Advanced Settings->Dialog Option it is set to launch form in dialog.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Are there any customizations to the environment or site, or page in question? Any custom JavaScript that's not executing properly or has an error could easily prevent the modal dialog from executing correctly. Are there any JavaScript errors on your page?

Comment: Webdes03 i dont see any javascript error in the page. Also i dont think there is any javascript applied to the page either.